# Generate DDL from Entities basing on JSR 303 Validator annotations

Tags: hibernate, ant

I am generating DDL from Hibernate entities. Some of the entities are using the JSR 303 validator annotations (javax.validation.constraints.Max - is one of them).

The DDL is generated using Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 CR1 + related Ant Task.

The problem is that all text columns (even though they may be limited by @Max(32)) are generated as VARCHAR(255). I have tried to debug the org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport class (and related). From what I have seen, there is no place during construction of org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column that would contain any logic related to Validator annotations.

I have also tried to modify 'hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl' property - without any success.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Components/Libraries:

- JDK 6
- Hibernate Validator 4.3.0 Final
- Hibernate Commons Annotations 4.0.2 Final
- Hibernate Core 4.2.2 Final
- Hibernate Entity Manager 4.2.2 Final

Rafal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hbm2ddl` doesn't consider JSR 303 annotations. That kind of makes sense from the point-of-view of the tool. It generates "code" (the DDL) for the database while JSR 303 aka bean-validation operates in the JVM.

To fix the size in the database you need to set the `length` property of the JPA `@Column` annotation. Yes, it's ugly that you need to duplicate the size constraint but that's the way it is.

Comment: But it also does ignore the Hibernate Validator annotations, like @Length. And in my previous configuration: Hibernate 3.3.2 + Hibernate Tools 3.4.0 it worked just fine. Any ideas ?

Comment: `@Length` is a non-JPA annotation proprietary to Hibernate. It's a simple shortcut for the two standard `@Min`/`@Max` annotations, right? I'd be surprised if `hbm2ddl` ever supported that but if you say so...Anyway, the only reliable option AFAIK is `@Column#length`.

Comment: Marcel - Yeah I am quite certain it did work - because we have upgraded version of Hibernate (core + tools + validator) and the generated DDL no longer correctly sets the length of text columns.

I could only assume it is due completely different initialization of HIbernate Validator in newer versions of Hibernate (possibly due to support of JSR 303). Hibernate's Metadata still gets updated (basing on constraints) but it happens by the means of org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator class which gets run when SessionFactory is created.

Anyway - thanks for your help. Cheers!

Comment: This answer isn't quite right, some BV constraints actually _are_ considered for DDL by Hibernate ORM. Please see my answer for a few reasons why you may not see this happening. Source: I'm member of the Hibernate team and just tested this feature successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`hbm2ddl` *does* consider a few Bean Validation constraints, namely `@NotNull`, `@Size`, `@Digits` and the legacy `@Length` constraint defined by Hibernate Validator.

If you don't see the constraints reflected in the DDL emitted by Hibernate ORM, reasons may be:

- You don't have a Bean Validation provider (such as Hibernate Validator) on the classpath; just the Bean Validation API JAR is not enough, as Hibernate ORM bootstraps an actual validation factory in order to obtain the constraint metadata
- You're not using validation mode `AUTO` or `DDL`. Only in those modes the constraints are propagated to the DDL